# Can you change the bit rate or quality in general for .png formats while rendering?

Tags: rendering

I noticed that you can change the bit rates for the FFmpegs and so on if you want to render in a video instantly. Is there any way to do it for pngs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG is not a lossy format like jpeg. It can vary the file size just with compression quality. Think of it as a zip packer. The more you set compression level, the more time it takes to compress, but the more compact file it produces, but after unpacking a file is the same. The compression level you can change in the output settings. Also PNG can be with or without alpha channel (RGBA / RGB). And also you can save 8 bit or 16 bit per channel color depth.
So, if you render to PNG, it's like rendering to bitmaps (BMP) and then compress them with zip. No quality degradation on any settings. Just time and file size - that's what you can play with.

Comment: What a nice answer :). Just to add - Some quality degradation occurs with PNGs - they're rather bad at saving accurate color information.

Comment: @Jachym Michal are you talking about the gamma correction? But that is nothing to do with PNG itself, it happens anytime you convert linear to sRGB space.Within 8 bits it does its best. Yes, if you want some post-processing, you'd better use some of "linear" formats (exr, hdr), but the file size... Though, using 16 bit png solves the problem to some extent (256 times better color resolution), and for some post it's pretty enough.

Comment: Hello :). Yes, that's mostly it. And *unassociated alpha* that can cause trouble during compositing. I'm no expert at this, just pointing out even PNG has limits, just so the OP isn't surprised later :).